# No Google Analytics Demographic data generated for iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics, app-store-connect

I've added Google Analytics to my iOS app and everything is working except for Demographics. I've followed the instructions on implementing demographics and added the following line of code to all my trackers:

```
tracker.allowIDFACollection = YES;
```

I've also added the linker flag

```
-force_load /path/to/libAdIdAccess.a
```

I'm not getting any warnings logged other than the success logs of my registered events.

When I look at App Overview and Real time Overview, I see all the events that I've registered from the app but when I look at Demographics Overview I see "There is no data for this view."

Version of Google Analytics that I'm using: 3.13

Is there anything else that I am missing?

**UPDATE:** I've even tried using the Google Analytics Sample project and I'm still not seeing any demographic data.

Answer (score 3):

Try to debug your app and make sure the IDFA is being sent to Google Analytics.

You also might not be reaching the threshold. [From the docs:](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2954071?hl=en&ref_topic=2799375)

> Thresholds are applied to prevent anyone viewing a report from
>   inferring the demographics or interests of individual users. When a
>   report contains Age, Gender, or Interest Category (as a primary or
>   secondary dimension, or as part of an applied segment), a threshold
>   may be applied and some data may be withheld from the report. For
>   example, if there are fewer than N instances of Gender=male in a
>   report, then data for the male dimension may be withheld.
>
> If a threshold has been applied to a report, you will see a notice
>   below the report title.

This basically means that there must be a minimum number of users before it can give you demographics data, so if this is a new app or not published yet just give it some time. The amount of users is not specified. But I suspect is something on the ballbark of 100 to 500. Of course that means 100 to 500 of users with demographics data, and not every user has an IDFA that is associated with demographics data.

Comment: Thanks for the information, is the IDFA information shown in the logs provided by GoogleAnalytics when registering an event?

Comment: It won't be necessarily sent with every single hit. But you should be able to see in the logs some signs that IDFA collection is working

Comment: I've just debugged both our Android app and iOS app and confirmed that the IDFA and AdId (for android) is being sent to Google. So It's probably the data threshold you were talking about. One other question, when we submit our iOS app to Apple, do we have to specify that we are using it to attribute campaigns served outside of the app?

Comment: OP, did you end up getting any data?

Comment: I wouldn't mind knowing if this was ever resolved myself. We;re in a similar situation with an app that has everything configured that we know of but no Demographics data displaying in GA.

Comment: @Joey what should we look for in the logs to determine whether the IDFA is being sent? I can see a client ID field `&cid` going out, is that it?